# Find combinations of two strings in multiple files

Tags: regex, powershell, full-text-search

I want to search through files in a folder and find the following strings in each file and I want to output it to a file.  I would like to find a combination of 2 strings in the files no matter how it is written in the file.  I should be able to find these combination of strings even if a carriage return exists in the middle of these 2 strings.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$Path = "C:\Promotion\Scripts"
$txt_string1 = "CREATE"
$txt_string2 = "PROC"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "C:\Promotion\Errors\Deployment_Errors.txt"

# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".sql".
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.sql" | 
   Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | 
   ForEach-Object { 
      If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $txt_string2) {
         $PathArray += $_.FullName
      }
   }

$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_} | Out-File $Results
```

Answer (score 0):

for find more than one  string in txt file You should Use like this method

```
   "hello","guy","hello guy" | Select-String -Pattern '(hello.*guy)|(guy.*hello)'
```

the result :

```
hello guy
```

after you find strings you want out-file 
like that:

```
"hello","guy","hello guy" | Select-String -Pattern '(hello.*guy)|(guy.*hello)' | Out-File -FilePath c:\test.txt
```

now we see in test.txt

```
PS C:\> Get-Content test.txt

hello guy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without loops. Define the combinations of your two search terms as alternatives in a regular expression with multiline support enabled (`(?ms)`).

```psh
$basepath = 'C:\Promotion\Scripts'
$results  = 'C:\Promotion\Errors\Deployment_Errors.txt'

$term1 = 'CREATE'
$term2 = 'PROC'
$pattern = "(?ms)($term1.*$term2|$term2.*$term1)"

Get-ChildItem "$basepath\*.sql" |
  ? { Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw | Select-String -Pattern $pattern } |
  select -Unique -Expand FullName |
  Out-File $results
```

Note that this will report any file that contains both terms anywhere in it, no matter what other text is between them. If you want to find only files that contain combinations of the two terms either not separated (`CREATEPROC` or `PROCCREATE`) or separated nothing but whitespace, change the pattern to this:

```psh
$pattern = "(?ms)($term1\s*$term2|$term2\s*$term1)"
```

Depending on your search terms it may also be a good idea to escape them before building the regular expression, so that you don't get unwanted meta characters (not likely with the two string literals you have, but just to be on the safe side):

```psh
$term1 = [regex]::Escape('CREATE')
$term2 = [regex]::Escape('PROC')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ansgar.

But the script still doesnt return when the term CREATE and PROC are on 2 different lines, the script you had provided above only works if the terms CREATE and PROC are on the same line in the file.

And I want the powershell script to identify files where the terms CREATE and PROC are next to each other whether they both be on the same line or in different lines in the file as long as these 2 terms follow each other immediately after the other it should show up in the results output file

Comment: @PavanSanthanam Apparently `Select-String` processes input files line by line, so the multiline match won't work. You need to read the entire content of a file as a single string and pass that into `Select-String`. See updated answer.